# Error in pkg-config when try to download git repository

Tags: go, dlib, pkg-config

I was trying to make a facial recognition app using Go and Kagami/go-face repository. It requires dlib-models. And I was used MSYS tool for get the distribution in windows.

But when I try to get the go repository using `go get github.com/Kagami/go-face` command and it gives an error:

> # pkg-config --cflags -- dlib-1

Any one had this issue before in windows 10.

Comment: I suspect your full error is ```pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in %PATH%``` (you put the command its failing to run)?. This package uses CGO (with [pkg-config](https://godoc.org/github.com/rjeczalik/pkgconfig/cmd/pkg-config)) so building it requires some additional tools. Currently under windows using [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) is recommended. You need to follow the [build instructions](https://github.com/Kagami/go-face#windows). [This issue](https://github.com/Kagami/go-face/issues/5) has a little more info.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I follow every instruction for windows installation. But i type "go-face" it gives -: bash: go-face: command not found.

Comment: This error--# pkg-config --cflags -- dlib-1, giving me when i try to download using go get command to download their repository

Answer (score 0):

As commented, [the README](https://github.com/Kagami/go-face#windows) lists the Windows pre-requisites, [involving MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).
This was from [commit 968bbf9](https://github.com/Kagami/go-face/commit/968bbf9ddf75661a8ab2168c25d61f3f1af4e217), following [issue 5 "Windows support?"](https://github.com/Kagami/go-face/issues/5)

Another approach would be to use Docker, with an [Ubuntu image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu), which would come with dlib, where you can add Go and experiment there.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. `pkg-config.exe` will be found in the path:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
```

if you installed MSYS2 on default path. Export

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
```

this path to environment variable then you wont get that error.